# How to include different html tags in the header for different pages?

Tags: php, images, css, html, headers

I am changing the banner in the header based on the page id:

```
 if(is_page(14) or is_page(16))
    { $class_name='bannerExp'; }
    if(is_page(18) or is_page(52) or is_page(22) or is_page(20))
    { $class_name='bannerD'; }
    if(is_page(27))
    {$class_name='bannerJ';}
     if(is_page(25))
    {$class_name='bannerS';}
   if(is_page(2))
    {$class_name='bannerH';}

<div class="<?php echo($class_name);?>">
```

class_name is a different css class that  loads different size and background image(banner) when the if statement is true:

```
.bannerExp{width: 100%; height: 440px; background-image: url(img/yyy.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;}
.bannerDev{width: 100%; height: 440px; background-image: url(img/zzz.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

I want also to inlude text or images inside the banner div when one of the pages is loaded. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign something to a variable and output that

```
    if(is_page(14) or is_page(16))
        { $class_name='bannerExp'; }
        if(is_page(18) or is_page(52) or is_page(22) or is_page(20))
        { $class_name='bannerD'; 
          $somevariable = 'test';
}
        if(is_page(27))
        {$class_name='bannerJ';}
         if(is_page(25))
        {$class_name='bannerS';}
       if(is_page(2))
        {$class_name='bannerH';}

    <div class="<?php echo($class_name);?>">
<?php (if $somevariable != '') { echo $somevariable;} ?>
```

That being said, this is a horrible way of doing things and you should look into custom page templates, rather than having to check for page id's and writing if statements for every case scenario... this defeats the point of having a cms.

Comment: `if( is_page( array(18, 52, 22, 20) ) )` is shorter and less distractive.

Comment: Thank you. I was abble to achieve what I needed. I will change the if statement as well.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Please set the issue as resolved.